# How can I stop UIView background colour from disappearing when I select a cell in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my tableView, I have a subView with a background colour of red and anytime I select a cell in the tableview the background colour disappears. I was wondering if there was a way to fix this?

Comment: select your table cell in storyboard and assign Selection property  is none

Answer (score 1):

You have to stop tableview cell selection style. Write below code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

`cell.selectionStyle = .none`

For set cell background color on selection.

`cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red` // here you can set your own custom color.

Comment: This works fine, but I want feedback that the cell was tapped. What I don't want is the elements in the cell to lose their background colour as a result of the tap.

Comment: In this case you can set another color for background of cell selection. If it's works then please accept the answer, Though other SO visitors can get help from the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

`cell.selectionstyle = .none`